# During PostNotificationname which view controller get first notification

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

In NSNotification broadcast which view Controller get first Notification?

Answer (score 0):

The order is undefined.  It may be the order in which observers register, or it may be random.  Apple makes no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we add postNotificationName when we click the button action or related methods.Once it calls directly or it goes to the viewController where you add the addObserver with same name of post notification in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 0):

It might be in stack order of your add observers. Means whichever you have added last add observer will receive first or top most controller on UIViewController stack will receive first.